# Excel work out fiscal year

Tags: excel

The fiscal year starts on July 1 and ends on June 30th.

I need to calculate the fiscal year + month in the following format

```
26/05/2006  2005011
26/05/2006  2005011
09/06/2006  2005012
15/06/2006  2005012
```

My current formula is below.

```
=YEAR(A2)&"0"&MOD(MONTH(A2)-7,12)+1
```

The problem is that the formula populates the current year and not based on the fiscal year.

```
25/05/2006  2006011
26/05/2006  2006011
26/05/2006  2006011
09/06/2006  2006012
15/06/2006  2006012
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use EDATE()

```
=YEAR(EDATE(A1,-6)) & "0" & TEXT(MONTH(EDATE(A1,-6)),"00")
```

[image]

Comment: simpler formula, I like it.

Comment: @ForwardEd but EDATE is new to 2010 if OP was using an older version yours would have been the answer.

Comment: Nice! +1. Anyway can be just `=TEXT(EDATE(A1;-6);"YYYY\0MM")`

Answer (score 2):

you need to do a check for the current date to see if it is before or after your breakpoint of june 30/july 1st.

```
=IF(A2<=Date(year(A2),6,30),Year(A2)-1,Year(A2))&"0"&MOD(MONTH(A2)-7,12)+1
```

So after you determine if you need to subtract 1 from your year or not, tack on the rest of your formula.

[image: proof of concept]